# In redis, does HSET affect an existing TTL on the hash?

Tags: redis

Simple scenario, but I have been unable to find confirmation one way or the other. My understanding is that normal keys have their TTL invalidated on a SET operation unless otherwise specified, but does anything happen to a hash TTL upon an HSET operation? Note that I am not asking about child key TTLs which do not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> altering the field value of a hash with HSET […] will leave the timeout untouched.

From https://redis.io/commands/expire/

Comment: Wow, I read that whole page too and it was right there. Thank you very much.